# Android, SQLite transactions and process freeze

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

I'm processing a lot of XML data that validates the local data storage within an AsyncTask object. First I tried to use transactions for these operations but while a transaction is in progress any other actions by the user will make the app freeze and wait for the transaction to finish, and sometimes even make the app stop responding.

The transactions are divided into several steps sometimes counting to a couple of hundreds per iteration. Because of the problems I went from using transactions to real-time queries which is very slow but solves the freezing - resulting in a very battery consuming application.

My question is; Is there a way to stop the transactions from locking the database? Or is my problem a result of poor preparation before the transactions?

Comment: You can implement a proper `ContentProvider` and use `ContentProviderOperation`s with a suitable number of calls to `ContentProviderOperation.Builder#withYieldAllowed()`. The best way to implement this pattern correctly is to copy the abstract class [SQLiteContentProvider](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-latform-packages/providers-CalendarProvider/com/android/providers/calendar/SQLiteContentProvider.java.htm) used by many providers in the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are tend to lock your table(s) while doing their business, so there's no way that you can play transactions and non-transactional queries on a same instance at same time.

However, what you need to do is to process your data (xml) first (which might be time consuming) and later kick-in transaction once you've got the data ready.

P.S. I would personally suggest you to make use of transactions (in an efficient way) when it comes to insert multiple records because it creates a single *Journal-file* to handle all the insertion and speeds up SQLite operations a lot.

Answer (score 0):

make your transactions smaller and don't forget (like I did) to still end transaction if exception thrown - use try, catch, finally...